# How to extend a method in php

Tags: php

For instance I have the following class

```
class myClassName{

    function funtionOne(){

        $a = '123';
        $b = '456';
        $c = '789';

        $d = 'var_value';
        $e = 'var_value';
        $f = 'var_value';
    }

    function funtionTwo(){
        $a = '123';
        $b = '456';
        $c = '789';

        $g = 'var_value';
        $h = 'var_value';
        $i = 'var_value';
    }

}
```

As you can see the variables $a, $b, $c are in both methods. My question is: How can I extend a method so get something like this:

```
class myClassName{

    function funtionABC(){
        $a = '123';
        $b = '456';
        $c = '789';
    }

    function funtionOne(){

        include functionABC's content here

        $d = 'var_value';
        $e = 'var_value';
        $f = 'var_value';
    }

    function funtionOne(){

        include functionABC's content here

        $g = 'var_value';
        $h = 'var_value';
        $i = 'var_value';
    }

}
```

Note: I do not want to return anything from the function, just want to retrieve the content, as you would with an include() or a trait. Thank you.

Comment: You can use member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class myClassName{
    public $a, $b, $c;

    function Init_funtionABC(){
        $this->a = '123';
        $this->b = '456';
        $this->c = '789';
    }

    function funtionOne(){

        Init_funtionABC();

        //you can access $this->a , $this->b , $this->c here

        $d = 'var_value';
        $e = 'var_value';
        $f = 'var_value';
    }

    function funtionOne(){

        Init_funtionABC();

        //you can access $this->a , $this->b , $this->c here

        $g = 'var_value';
        $h = 'var_value';
        $i = 'var_value';
    }

}
```

Comment: If those member variables be used inside that class only then they should be private.

Comment: Yeah. That is just an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I would still have to do 
$a = $this->a;

Comment: Why you have already `$this->a` you can use it.

Comment: I would still have to do 
`$a = $this->a; $b = $this->b; $c = $this->c`; within each of the methods. My goal is not to redeclare the variables in each method and still be able to use the compact() php function to pass those variables to a Laravel view.  However this is a right answer for the question asked.

Comment: Then you need to init method on constructor, so you do not need to redeclare on each methods or use global var. Still am not clear you exact usecase